# Flutter in_app_purchase queryProductDetails method breaking app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Fetching products from Google is problem. Actually building it in flutter after calling queryProductDetails. If i enter set of wrong ID flutter do not have to build any object and it not crashing app, but when I flutter receive something and starting building objects app is crashing with log:

> E/AndroidRuntime(22618): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual
> method getIntroductoryPriceCycles()Ljava/lang/String; in class
> Lcom/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails; or its super classes
> (declaration of 'com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails' appears in
> /data/app/com.icd.tourguide-QLilN64t5w0c7y2_ABuIxA==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> io.flutter.plugins.inapppurchase.Translator.fromSkuDetail(Translator.java:27)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> io.flutter.plugins.inapppurchase.Translator.fromSkuDetailsList(Translator.java:49)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> io.flutter.plugins.inapppurchase.MethodCallHandlerImpl$1.onSkuDetailsResponse(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:185)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> com.android.billingclient.api.zzj.run(com.android.billingclient:billing@@3.0.0:8)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:900)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8347)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native
> Method) E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
> E/AndroidRuntime(22618):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
> I/Process (22618): Sending signal. PID: 22618 SIG: 9

What I am doing is:

```
InAppPurchaseConnection _iap = InAppPurchaseConnection.instance;
bool available = await _iap.isAvailable();
if(available) {
final ProductDetailsResponse response = await _iap.queryProductDetails({"token_test"});
}
```

I saw this issue for example
[in-app purchase crashes when fetching products from the Play Store in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62363025/in-app-purchase-crashes-when-fetching-products-from-the-play-store-in-flutter)

But I do not have com.android.billingclient:billing in my project.